# Can arguments have line breaks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a elementary question. Suppose I'm using jQuery inserting the following:

```
<div>
    <img src="foo.jpg"/>
    <p>foo bar</p>
</div>
```

Can I only write it inline like the this:

```
$("#foo bar").append("<div><img src="foo.jpg"/><p>foo bar</p></div>")
```

, or can I somehow keep the line break and indentation of the original code?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sindresorhus/multiline.

Comment: Use `\\` for line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
$("#foo bar").append('<div>'+
                         '<img src="foo.jpg"/>'+
                         '<p>foo bar</p>'+
                     '</div>');
```